# Alternative to Rotation degrees or clock facing to describe cards angle

Tags: card-game

I'm working on some ideas for a system and hit a minor roadblock.

I would like to identify the angle of a card placed on a playing field. Besides a clock facing identification (3:00 would be a landscape position) or degrees (90 degrees would be a landscape position) are there any other terms that can be used to describe this angle?

I would like to find a different terminology for telling players (in the rules) to turn their cards to a landscape position, or portrait, etc. This may be unanswerable, but I could swear I have heard someone refer to an angle in an engineering environment that wasn't degrees or clock facings.

Comment: Navies have traditionally used *a 32-point compass* for describing ship heading. Every second point has a traditional name: N, NNE, NE, ENE, E, ESE, SE, SSE, S, SSW, SW, WSW, W, WNW, N, NNW.

Comment: It would be helpful to know roughly what level of precision you're after. Degrees gives you 360 possibilities, which is likely overkill for a card game. Clock facing gives you 12, and the naval system mentioned above gives 32. Your question suggests you only need 2 (portrait/landscape).  Some games invent there own terminology for this, such as "tapped" status in Magic: The Gathering.

Comment: My thought process is a 'standardized' system, with no more angles than a clock face has (thinking the major hours) but no less than say 6 angles. I want to be able to refer to a cards angle very much similar to "CARD AT 3 O'CLOCK" angle.